# php mPDF, impossible to set font-family and font-size

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, fonts

Ok after so much time spent reading their documentation, and my tests I decided to consult the SO community for a help.

I use mPDF to generate pdf from HTML. The library works fine, pdf is produced etc.

But I wasn't able to set the font-family and font-size as I want it.

Code I tried:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4');
$mpdf->CSSselectMedia='mpdf';
$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
$mpdf->setBasePath($url);
$mpdf->SetHeader($url);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetFooter($url);
$mpdf->Output($filename.'.pdf', 'I');
```

In my stylesheet with mpdf media, I have bunch of styles that are dealing with all of the html code. And I also have some rules for the font-family and the font-size ie:

```
body{
        border: none;
        font-size: 10pt;
        colosr:#000;
        font-family: Times, Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif !important;
    }
```

But the font settings are not apllied at all.

I also tried the following params on instantiation:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('UTF-8', 'A4',9, 'dejavuserif');
```

But still nothing. I still have sans-serif in the pdf, and also in very big size.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you look at https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-5-x.html

Comment: @Phil Yes I already read that as well as other sections of the documentation, but still, whatever I try I cannot change these things.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways with which u can add your font to generated pdf:

**1. Setting font to mpdf**

Keep your fonts in ttfonts folder in mpdf lib. Then, in config_fonts.php file add your font in array :

> $this->fontdata = array(
>       "YourNewFont" => array(
>           'R' => "YourNewFont.ttf"));

Then set font to the mpdf object using :

> $mpdf->SetFont('YourNewFont');

Now, your fornt is set. Using $mpdf->WriteText('My Text'); will add text to pdf with the set font.

**2. Use font in Html**

Add your font family in a css file using **@font-face {}**

Then, import that css file like below:

> $stylesheet = file_get_contents('MyStyleWithFont.css');
>
> $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

Now, you can use your font with html. Define font-family for the text in either css file or inline with html. Use **$mpdf->WriteHTML(My Text);** to print html.

Comment: how to set font size ?

Comment: What `$this->fontdata`? What is $this in your context?

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm late, hope it would be helpful for someone in future.
While creating mPDF object set the mod parameter as 'UTF-8' or ' ' instead of 'c'. 
'c' will force system to use core fonts only and thus neglect the custom font.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('UTF-8','A4')
```

Note: this is applicable for mPDF v6 and below